# (MEAN STACK) nothing happens when i use put method to update a document

Tags: node.js, angular, express, crud, mean-stack

i have an application that's supposed to do CRUD, very simple. i want to update a book's info but it doesn't work so what should i change ?
plus i'm getting this error now :

*core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')*

**backend code :**

```
//EDIT ONE BOOK BY NAME
  booksRoute.route('/edit/:name').put((req,res,next)=>{
        BookModel.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.name,
            {$set:false},
            (error,data)=>{
                if (error){
                    console.log(error); 
                    return next(error); 
                }else{
                    res.json(data) ; 
                    console.log('data updated successfully');
                }
            })
  })
```

**FRONTEND CODE :**

```
<div id="bg"><div class="addme">
    <ul>
        <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" ngNativeValidate>  
        <li>
        <label>book's name *</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" required>
        </li>
        <li>
        <label>book's genre *</label>
        <input name="genre" type="text" ngModel required>
        </li>
        <li>
        <label>book's author *</label>
        <input name="author" type="text" ngModel required>
        </li>
        <li>
        <label>rating *</label>
        <input name="rating" type="number" [max]="10" min="0" ngModel required>
        </li>
        <li>
        <label>price *</label>
        <input name="price" type="number"  ngModel required>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"/> 
        </li>  
    </form>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**service**

```
//edit one book by it's name
  editBook(name:string, data){
    return this.http.put(this.backendUrl +'/edit/'+name,data) ;
  }
```

**edit-component.ts**

```
onSubmit(f){
    console.log("name value:" + f.name.value)
    this.apiService.editBook(f.name.value,f.value).subscribe( res => {console.log('backend\' response:',res)}) ;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the solution after reading documentations.
i have two obvious mistakes in my code, the first one is that i didn't assign my input field that i'm gonna use to filter the update request to [(ngModel)] ('name').
so it's like this **in my template**:

```
<li>
        <label>book's name *</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="f.name" required>
        </li>
```

the next mistake is that findOneAndUpdate method is **missing the request body** so it should be like this to work :

```
//EDIT ONE BOOK BY NAME
  booksRoute.route('/edit/:name').put((req,res,next)=>{
        BookModel.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.name,req.body,
            {new:true},
            (error,data)=>{
                if (error){
                    console.log(error); 
                    return next(error); 
                }else{
                    console.log(data)
                    res.json(data) ; 
                    console.log('data updated successfully');
                }
            })
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

so the problem is you are not specifying a field to update do something like this:

```js
  booksRoute.route('/edit/:name').put((req,res,next)=>{
        BookModel.findOneAndUpdate({ name: req.params.name },
            {$set: {
               fieldname: false
            }},
            (error,data)=>{
                if (error){
                    console.log(error); 
                    return next(error); 
                }else{
                    res.json(data) ; 
                    console.log('data updated successfully');
                }
            })
  })
```

**Edit**: I have updated the code indeed there was a mistake I was not passing the filter correctory I have changed that so now it should work.

also, if you want to learn more visit this [site](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html)

Comment: i tried ur solution but i have this error showing up :                                                        ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value').                                i think it's pointing to an error in my submit function but i didn't find how to fix it yet                                                                
    onSubmit(f){
    console.log("name value:" + f.name.value)
    this.apiService.editBook(f.name.value,f.value).subscribe( res => {console.log('backend\' response:',res)}) ; 
  }